# Connecting Celery to Redis via Sentinel

Tags: redis, celery, redis-sentinel

How do I tell celery about the service name I am looking for on redis? I am trying to use the built-in Sentinel support in Celery 4. I am passing a broker URL configured as it says to in [the documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html#redis-support-for-sentinel): `sentinel://0.0.0.0:26379`

But redis appears to complain about not being passed a service_name:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/sentinel.py", line 222, in discover_master
    raise MasterNotFoundError("No master found for %r" % (service_name,))
OperationalError: No master found for None
```

Is it possible to pass a service_name using this URL format? I have tried

```
sentinel://0.0.0.0:26379/my_service
sentinel://0.0.0.0:26379/0/my_service
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on the connection URLs—I have found [redis-sentinel-URL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Redis-Sentinel-Url/1.0.0) but I don't see it included in the redis package, so I am not even sure it is being used by redis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to sort this out: celery needs both the `broker_url` and `broker_transport_options` configuration to be set.

1) `broker_url` takes the form of a sentinel URL: 
sentinel://localhost:26379

2) `broker_transport_options` is a dictionary that needs the name of the sentinel service you are trying to connect to. i.e., if you want to push jobs to a queue called 'fiddlesticks':
{"master_name":"fiddlesticks"}

Though the error message above is complaining that you passed in the wrong 'service_name', you actually want to pass in using the key 'master_name'.

Comment: Hi Desiree, what does "fiddlesticks" mean here? Can you specify a default job queue if you don't know a specific one?

Comment: In my example my queue name is 'fiddlesticks', I don't know how to specify a default job queue.