# Connecting Celery to Redis Sentinel

Tags: redis, celery, sentinel, redis-sentinel

How come celery cannot find my sentinel service?

I have:

```
app.conf.broker_url = "sentinel://192.168.29.11:26379"
app.conf.broker_transport_options = {"master_name": "mymaster"}
```

And what I am getting is:

```
{"message": "consumer: Cannot connect to sentinel://192.168.29.11:26379: No master found for None.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)", 
"level": "ERROR", 
"logger": "celery.worker.consumer.consumer"}
```

Why is there "No master found for None" when I am specifying the master_name?

Comment: Can you check if this works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43196507/8482471

Comment: @rajkris As I wrote in my original question, I already have what they write in the post you linked and it is still not working. So the linked question is not relevant.

Comment: Can you confirm the sentinal.conf in the question?

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, had another app.conf.broker_transport_options defined elsewhere and it overwrote the setting.